# Xcode Version 10.3 ITMS-90035: Invalid Signature

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, code-signing

I am trying to upload a signed ipa file to the app store but I keep receiving an error message saying:

> ITMS-90035: Invalid Signature - A sealed resource is missing or invalid. The file at path [Inuttut.app/Inuttut] is not properly signed. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate.

I'm building the app with Cordova/Ionic 3. I have a valid Distribution signing certificate and provisioning profile for the app. I have triple checked that the bundle id is correct, and I have also set the Xcode build to use the [legacy build](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/407).

One thing that has me wondering is that when I'm in Xcode and select "Automatically manage signing" it sets my signing certificate to iPhone Developer instead of iPhone Distribution. Signing the app this way and uploading it produces the same error as unchecking "Automatically manage signing" and manually selecting the iPhone Distribution certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. Frustratingly, it had nothing to do with my distribution certificate or anything like that, so kudos to Apple for the wild goose chase. It was simply because I have some assets which have non-ASCII characters in the filename. This is exactly the kind of linguistic bias that makes developing software for non European languages difficult. In any case, I recommend looking for any files like that - hopefully my pain and suffering over the past few days will help somebody else.

P.S contacting Apple directly was a fruitless and infuriating experience, so don't bother.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and fix by suggestion in your answer. But I want to provide some more detail to make it more clear

For me this problem was fixed by changing `Product Name` from our local `unicode` name to `ascii` english name

Keep in mind that `Product Name` differs from `Display Name` which is displayed below app icon as your app name. So don't worry about changing `Product Name` requires change your app name, just choose an `ascii` name and error gone

[image]

Comment: Interesting - I had some bundled audio files that had non-ascii characters in them that caused this problem. this is helpful too though. thanks!